# How to add a second class in javascript using file url inside a directory?

Tags: javascript, jquery, expression, filepath, addclass

I am using the following javascript to add the class based on url name.

```
$(function(){
    var loc = window.location.pathname.match(/^\/?(\w+)\b/);
    if(loc) $(document.body).addClass(loc[1].toLowerCase());
}
```

It is working fine except when the file is inside the directory it only adds the folder name and not the file name. I have added a second variable to add however I don't have the right expression it keeps adding the whole url products/nameoffile.php as the class

```
$(function(){
    var loc = window.location.pathname.match(/^\/?(\w+)\b/);
    var loc2 = window.location.pathname.match(/^\/?(.*)\b/);
    if(loc) $(document.body).addClass(loc[1].toLowerCase());
    if(loc2) $(document.body).addClass(loc2[1].toLowerCase());
}
```

I would like to know the right expression for adding the class to add for the second class for a file inside a directory. Instead of 'products/nameoffile.php' i want just 'nameoffile' for the class to be added to body.

Comment: You should be able to combine your regexes into something like `/^\/?(\w+)(.*)\b/` which will return an array containing the pieces. My regex is likely not quite what you need, but it's just a quick example

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$(function(){
    var loc = window.location.pathname.split("/");
    if (loc[loc.length-1]) {
       var cls = loc[loc.length-1]].split('.');
       $('body').addClass(cls[0].toLowerCase());
   }
})
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jKPCj/2/)

Comment: This works on the main directory. But when I create folder named 'products' and place this code on the product pages but it doesn't add the correct class name. It uses the name of the directory instead of the filename.

Answer (score 0):

Not using a regex but maybe this will point you in the right direction.

http://jsfiddle.net/aTnyk/

Answer (score 0):

Don't use regex, just use a simple `split()` and `pop()`:

```
var loc = window.location.pathname.split('/').pop();
```